# How to Calculate the Area of a Triangle with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a table with two boxes in which you type the height and the base of a triangle and then you can get the resulting area at the bottom this is what I got so far as for the other shapes. But I can not figure it out for a triangle. I am new so sorry in advance.

```
    <h3>Calculo de Areas</h3>
        <p>Ingrese la Informacion requerida para sacar el Area de las siguientes Figuras.</p>
        <p>Nota:Los Resultados estan dados en la misma unidad que se introduce.</p>
            <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
<p>
  <label>Radio de un Circulo</label>
  <input id="inputradio" type="number" placeholder="Radio" oninput="LengthConverter9(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter9(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Area: <span id="outputArea"></span></p>

<script>    
function LengthConverter9(valNum9) {
  document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML=(valNum9*valNum9)*3.14159265359;
}
                </script>
            </th><th>
<p>
  <label>Lado de un Cuadrado</label>
  <input id="inputLado" type="number" placeholder="Largo" oninput="LengthConverter10(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter10(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Area: <span id="outputArea1"></span></p>

<script>
function LengthConverter10(valNum10) {
  document.getElementById("outputArea1").innerHTML=(valNum10*valNum10);
}
</script>

    <tr><th>
        <p>
  <label>Base de un Triangulo Rectangulo</label>
  <input id="inputBase" type="number" placeholder="Ancho" oninput="LengthConverter11(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter11(this.value)">
</p>
        <p>
  <label>Altura de dicho Triangulo</label>
  <input id="inputAltura" type="number" placeholder="Alto" oninput="LengthConverter12(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter12(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Area: <span id="outputArea4"></span></p>
<script>    
function LengthConverter11(valNum11){
  document.getElementById("outputMetros4").innerHTML=(LengthConverter11*LengthConverter12)/2;
}
                </script>


        </th></tr>
    </table>
```

The only one that i cant get to work is the triangle one, Thanks in advance.

Comment: ¿Estás preguntando por el área del triángulo pero luego al final dices que la única que pudiste sacar es el triangulo?

Comment: Can you post a snippet or jsfiddle for your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this

```
  <input id="inputAltura" type="number" placeholder="Alto" oninput="LengthConverter12(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter12(this.value)">
```

You haven't define any function for `LengthConverter12`

Looking at this (calculating area of triangle)

```
document.getElementById("outputMetros4").innerHTML=(LengthConverter11*LengthConverter12)/2;
```

You are multipy a function defined by an undefined function?

I suggest you place all your js codes in one section, this way it is very easy to debug and read. However using your layout and building on what you have, here is a snippet below

```html
<h3>Calculo de Areas</h3>
<p>Ingrese la Informacion requerida para sacar el Area de las siguientes Figuras.</p>
<p>Nota:Los Resultados estan dados en la misma unidad que se introduce.</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <p>
        <label>Radio de un Circulo</label>
        <input id="inputradio" type="number" placeholder="Radio" oninput="LengthConverter9(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter9(this.value)">
      </p>
      <p>Area: <span id="outputArea"></span></p>

      <script>
        function LengthConverter9(valNum9) {
          document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = (valNum9 * valNum9) * 3.14159265359;
        }
      </script>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>
        <label>Lado de un Cuadrado</label>
        <input id="inputLado" type="number" placeholder="Largo" oninput="LengthConverter10(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter10(this.value)">
      </p>
      <p>Area: <span id="outputArea1"></span></p>

      <script>
        function LengthConverter10(valNum10) {
          document.getElementById("outputArea1").innerHTML = (valNum10 * valNum10);
        }
      </script>

      <tr>
        <th>
          <p>
            <label>Base de un Triangulo Rectangulo</label>
            <input id="inputBase" type="number" placeholder="Ancho">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Altura de dicho Triangulo</label>
            <input id="inputAltura" type="number" placeholder="Alto" oninput="LengthConverter11(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter11(this.value)">
          </p>
          <p>Area: <span id="outputArea4"></span></p>
          <script>
            function LengthConverter11(height) {
              var base = document.getElementById("inputBase").value.trim();
              console.log(base, height);
              height = height.trim();

              document.getElementById("outputArea4").innerHTML = (base * height) / 2;
            }
          </script>


        </th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function LengthConverter11() you are calling LengthConverter11 and LengthConverter12, these are functions, not variables. What you Need to do is a function to retrieve both values, and then you perform the operation.
example:

```
<input id="inputBase" type="number" placeholder="Ancho" name="triangleBase">
<input id="inputAltura" type="number" placeholder="Largo" name="triangleAltura" onchange="areaCalculator(this.value)">
<script>
  function areaCalculator(){
    var base = document.getElementById('inputBase').value;
    var altura = document.getElementById('inputAltura').value ; 
    document.getElementById("outputMetros4").innerHTML= (base*altura)/2;
  }
<script>
```

Something like that, I haven't tested it so, I don't know if its accurate, but basicly is what you need to do.